# How to test the random redirectUrl using sinon stub in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, chai, sinon

In controller I am redirecting to another url with query params as a state. State is nothing but random UUID. Like given below the controller.

**test.controller.ts**

```
import {Request,Response} from "express";
import {v4 as uuid} from "uuid";

export function test(req:Request,res:Response){
const state=uuid();
console.log(state) // 110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1
if(true){
    const url=`https://testurl/user?state=${state}`;
    res.redirect(302,url);
  }
}
```

and the unit test file like below

**test.controller.spec.ts**

```
import {Request,Response} from "express";
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import {expect} from 'chai';
import * as proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

descripbe('shoud redirect',()=>{
  const validurl:string="https://testurl/user?state=110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1";
  let res:any;
  let req:any
  let resstub:{calledWith:any};

  beforeEach(()=>{
    res={
        redirect:()=>{}
    }

    resstub = sinon.stub(res,'redirect');
  });

 it('should redirect with valid url',()=>{
    const urlctl=proxyquire('test-contriller',{});
    urlctl.test(req,res);
    expect(resstub.calledWith(302,validurl)).to.be.true;
})
})
```

when I validate the redirectUrl part it's getting failed because the state value is chaining every time randomly. Can please assist how to do I validate

Answer (score 1):

From the doc [How to use Link Seams with CommonJS](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/). We will be using `proxyquire` to construct our seams so that we can stub the `v4` function exported from the `uuid` package.

`controller.ts`:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

export function test(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const state = uuid();
  if (true) {
    const url = `https://testurl/user?state=${state}`;
    res.redirect(302, url);
  }
}
```

`controller.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

describe('shoud redirect', () => {
  let res: any;
  let req: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    res = { redirect: sinon.stub() };
  });

  it('should redirect with valid url', () => {
    const uuidv4Stub = sinon.stub().returns('110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1');
    const urlctl = proxyquire('./controller', {
      uuid: { v4: uuidv4Stub },
    });
    urlctl.test(req, res);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(
      res.redirect,
      302,
      'https://testurl/user?state=110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1',
    );
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
  shoud redirect
    ✓ should redirect with valid url (1592ms)


  1 passing (2s)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.ts |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 6                 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```